# C++ display cURL progress meter during download

Tags: c++, curl, osx-mountain-lion

I was going to attempt to display the progress meter during a cURL download by using the system() command. With the following method,

```
char command[] = "curl -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt -k https://www.example.com/data/format/json' > ~/location/file.json";
system( command );
```

the progress meter ([pretty much as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125601/capture-progress-from-command-line)) is printed to stdout, but I need to somehow capture that to display it in my app. The code is halted at the `system()` command until the download is finished, so I don't seem to have a way of doing anything in the code while the cURL command is downloading.

So I'm wondering if I'm missing some magical [cURL option](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), if there are alternatives or methods to `system()` that I may have missed, or if anybody has any other helpful pointers to how the progress meter may be piped to a stringstream in real-time, or something like that.

Mac 10.8.5

Comment: You have two options: One is to use [`popen`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/popen.3.html) to be able to read from the programs `stdout`. The other option is to use the [cURL *library*](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) and handle it all yourself (it's not that hard).

Comment: Looking into these options now, thanks.